# What are token types and the vocabulary in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I couldn't find any good resource online that describes this well. Does "token type" mean the types we encounter in a programming language like int, string, char etc.? I see that it is some integer, but what does this integer mean? And what is a vocabulary? Looking for some explanation with a simple bare minimum grammar.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Definitive-ANTLR-4-Reference/dp/1934356999

Comment: I have that but that doesn’t explain it

Comment: The integers have no meaning themselves, as "These symbols are equated with integer "token types" for efficient comparison at run-time." http://web.mit.edu/dmaze/school/6.824/antlr-2.7.0/doc/vocab.html

Comment: what is the difference between vocbulary and tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of token types and also the vocabulary is so simple that nobody probably thought about formally describing them. But here it is:

1. During the lexing process the Lexer assigns numbers to parts of the input text. That means a mapping is created between specific patterns in the input and an arbitrary number. This number is called the token type.

The lexer rules in a grammar describe the patterns which must be matched and the lexer rule names are the textual expression of the token that is created out of the matched input. Usually lexer rules get the token type assigned in the order they appear in the grammar. The first lexer rule gets token type 0, the next token type 1 and so on. In some situations (imported grammars or token vocabularies or virtual tokens) this order can be different, however.

2. A vocabulary is a generated structure to map a token type to its literal rule name. This is used in cases where you need the name for error messages, code completion or debugging.

Note: there's no such structure to map rule names back to token values (or in the case of the parser from rule names to rule indices). The reason is that a rule can return a different token type than what is defined by the rule name. For example consider this lexer rule from the MySQL grammar:

```
CHARACTER_SYMBOL: C H A R A C T E R -> type(CHAR_SYMBOL);
```

`CHARACTER_SYMBOL` is a rule with an own token value, but it returns the token value for `CHAR_SYMBOL` instead (type aliasing). Hence you can easily map from the token value to either of these rule names, but not the other way around.